# SystemVerilog array of parameters/constants

Tags: fpga, verilog, hdl, synthesis

If I have code like this:

```
logic [15:0] arr [0:3];
assign arr = {'d0, 'd1, 'd2, 'd3};

reg [1:0] k;
reg [63:0] out;

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    out <= {{16'd0}, {arr[k]}, 
            {arr[k+1]}, {arr[k+2]};
    k   <= k+2;
end
```

Is this valid syntax and will it synthesize into a multiported ROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's valid syntax for SystemVerilog, but not synthesizable. I'm assuming `k` gets a value from some code you have not shown. Then you cannot assign it inside the `always` block as shown.

And you probably should define `arr` as a parameter, not as a variable

```
parameter logic [15:0] arr [0:3] = {'d0, 'd1, 'd2, 'd3};
```

It probably won't synthesize to a ROM. More likely a mux that gets optimized with constant inputs.

Comment: If I use the way you have shown it, is it synthesizable? I'm using k here as an index and it gets updated based on some conditions. And can I use out <= {arr[k+3]}; with the syntax that you specified? Is it synthesizable?

Comment: You can only update `k` or any variable from one process to be synthesiable. Why are you assigning it to 0?

Comment: Have updated the code in the question

Comment: would you like to recommend any books for sv synthesis? Have you authored a book on this topic?

Comment: @lousycoder, your synthesis tool should have documentation for the synthesis rules.